# how to join one to many and keep the same total amount

Tags: t-sql, join, reporting-services, sum

I have Table A with one row  that have a total Premium for policy # and QuoteID. 
[image]

I need to JOIN it to table B that has many rows with the same Policy# and QuoteID but different WeightCode and ClassCode.

[image]

How can I join those two tables so i can keep only one total (WP) from Table A?
Because later on, when I will sum(WP) in SSRS it will give me wrong number.

Lets say I want something like that with only one WP =16630 and rest is 0:

[image]

Comment: IMO you're tackling the wrong problem; aka you're fixing a symptom not addressing the problem, or your approach is flawed. You don't want 0's for the other values, you want to aggregate (sum) before you join and get the inflated values  or just use the min/max value for each quiteID or use an analytic sum using quoteID as the partition.  It seems you do want all the records from table B, it's just effecting your sum.  Without knowing "later on" what tables are involved and what you need to sum, can't really help much more.  Show the actual problem; don't allude to it.

Comment: If you truly want to return all records but the value in only one of them, then what business rule woudl determine which one?

Comment: What would be the PK in Table B?

Comment: Later on in SSRS I have to break down data by only Month and Year. But I also have to create parameter with ClassCode. So I dont have to display ClassCode and WeightClass columns...BUT i will have to be able to exclude/include class code in total WP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, that it seems like you're trying to fix the wrong problem.  If you're using SSRS then you can have multiple datasets that you could use in different parts of the report.  You would get your first data set as `TableA` and the second dataset would be `TableB`.  I believe that may be your best option.

But if you truly want that dataset in one query, this should do it:

```
SELECT 
    b.QuoteID,
    b.PolicyNumber,
    b.WeightClass,
    b.SecondaryLiabFactor,
    b.ClassCode,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.QuoteID ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) = 1 THEN a.WP
        ELSE 0 
    END,
    a.YearNum,
    a.MonthNum
FROM TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.QuoteID = b.QuoteID
```

It uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to check if it's the first record in the join and returns the `WP` value if so, otherwise it will display `0`.  The `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` is there just because you don't need the row number to be based on any explicit order.

Comment: #jtate. Thanks for your advice. It perfectly works for part of my project. But now i have to join something even worse. Maybe you'll have a sec to look at it?    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622393/how-to-join-many-to-many-and-keep-the-same-total-amount